# Trying to remember an anime - nerdy pervy nosebleedy guy transforms into cool handsome guy every episode

Tags: story-identification, anime

A friend was mentioning the anime nosebleed trope recently, and I had this vague memory of the first time I ever saw it, but no amount of web searching/tv troping/etc have helped me find it, and now I am almost worried that I have some facts wrong. Let's see how close I can get...

Main character is a loser. He's pervy, girl-obsessed, and CONSTANTLY getting nosebleeds from seeing pretty ladies. At some point, he is afflicted (?) with a curse that temporarily turns him into a classic hunky anime guy. I think he gets taller, gets drawn more 'seriously', and his voice changes to that of a smooth guy when he's like that. I think there's a trigger for the change... maybe touching a woman? or getting the nosebleed? But he always goes back to normal at some point (possibly always at the worst possible time).

I probably saw this around like... the year 2000? 2001?, so I'd place it mid-late 90s or so. Also I don't know if it helps, but I think he had hair kinda like the yugioh guy. It had fanservice, but nothing super explicit (at least I hope not, because i watched it in a university theatre room with a bunch of other awkward teenage dudes).

Comment: The nosebleed thing was a common anime trope, but I haven't seen it recently. It is supposed to indicate lecherous thoughts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**DNA2: Dokoka de Nakushita Aitsu no Aitsu (1994)**

> Karin, a DNA operator from the future, is on a mission to change the course of history by stopping Momonari Junta from becoming the Mega-Playboy who fathered 100 children and led to the overpopulation of the world. But Junta is no playboy; in fact he is allergic to girls. But when Karin shoots him with the wrong DNA-altering bullet, he starts sporadically becoming the Mega-Playboy capable of charming any woman. Karin must try to restore the situation to normal before the change to Mega-Playboy becomes irreversible. 
> Source: [aniSearch.com](https://www.anisearch.com/anime/3393,dna2-dokoka-de-nakushita-aitsu-no-aitsu)

This is the only anime that comes to mind, but it doesn't fit your description completely. Or maybe allergic is an euphemism for nosebleeds. The haircut is close enough:

[image]

Comment: Oh WOW this is it! Thank you so much! I clearly misremembered a lot of the details here, but you found it... incredible work @Ocean !!